# serialize для сохранения в db

Tags: php, sql

Реализовую что-то вроде стены ВКонтакте - посты, текст, вложения... Для хранения поста создал класс с конструктором и гетерами. Вопрос такой: можно ли при помощи serialize() сохранять пост одной строкой в БД, и наскольно это неправильно?

Comment: Примерно на 95% неправильно. Ситуации с необходимостью хранения данных в неструктурированном виде есть, но это не одна из них, да и сохранять лучше стоит в чем-нибудь, что будет легко читаться любой платформой (json/protobuf/менее удобные варианты)

Comment: В принципе можно, но при этом вы лишаетесь вообще всех преимуществ использования БД. Вы не сможете фильтровать запрос по времени/автору/еще чему, не сможете вносить в него осознанные изменения (отредактировано тогда-то например), не сможете строить нормальные деревья ответов и т.д.

Comment: Вы хотите сериализовать сам пост и его мета-данные? А в чем глубинный смысл этого?

Comment: Если используется актуальная версия postgress или mysql, можно в поле с типом json хранить json объект. Но подумайте, не понадобятся ли вам фильтры при выборке и сортировке? Гораздо удобнее использовать стандартный подход. Если используется mongoDB, то только json :)